# Airflow: Execution date is in future when triggering manually from web-ui

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have upgraded Airflow to v1.10.7.

The DAG tasks are successful when running at scheduled time. But when I trigger a DAG in the UI, tasks are failed.

dag start_date defined to 1 year ago and catchup set False.

Checked the task log and observed that few nano second difference caused the issue.

```
{taskinstance.py:649} INFO - Dependencies not met for <TaskInstance: dag1.task1 2020-02-26T06:07:00.708296+00:00 [queued]>, dependency 'Execution Date'
 FAILED: Execution date 2020-02-26T06:07:00.708296+00:00 is in the future (the current date is 2020-02-26T06:06:31.997784+00:00).
```

Can you please help to fix this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We recently saw this issue, and discovered that the system clocks on our scheduler and worker nodes were not in sync. After installing the network time protocol daemons our jobs began executing as expected.

On a `yum` managed system:

```sh
sudo yum install -y ntp
sudo systemctl enable --now ntpd
```